# Get data from execute action

Tags: android, android-studio, execute

there is any way that I can get the return data from execute action?

for example I have the next line that calls to the execute function - `googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);` and the **googlePlacesReadTask** return some parser data to me. So how can I get this data that the action return to me ?

AsyncTask -

```
public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer,    List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

    List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
    Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

    try {
        googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
        googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    }

    if(String.valueOf(googlePlacesList) != "[]"){
        //Find the place
    }
    else{
        //No place found
    }
    return googlePlacesList;

}


}
```

second AsyncTask -

```
public class GooglePlacesReadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
String googlePlacesData = null;
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {
    try {
        googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
        String googlePlacesUrl = (String) inputObj[1];
        Http http = new Http();
        googlePlacesData = http.read(googlePlacesUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Google Place Read Task", e.toString());
    }

    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    PlacesDisplayTask placesDisplayTask = new PlacesDisplayTask();
    Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
    toPass[0] = googleMap;
    toPass[1] = result;
    placesDisplayTask.execute(toPass);
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @what you are using to get data like (AsynckTask) or any other method?

Comment: @Jack Yes I use AsyncTask

Comment: Please post your asynctask

Comment: @Jack I added the AsyncTask

Comment: @ali, where is your googlePlacesReadTask class/method?

Comment: @Jack This is my second AsyncTask  I added this also.

Comment: @Dr.ali you have data in googlePlacesData list. when you get response you have data in googlePlacesData  variable

Comment: @Jack So how can I use the AsyncTask data from my another class ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Which type of data you want to get from that method. If that method returns String data then save it in String variable.

**For example :** 
In your case if googlePlacesReadTask returns String type of data then store it in string variable like :

```
String data = googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: In my case it's an  AsyncTask so the return value in my case is AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String>. In this case how can I save it in variable and convert it to String ? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, In this case you will get your data in onPostExecute() method, because after completion of background process (i.e. doInBackground) onPostExecute() method gets called. Just print the value in result string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onPostExecute` method of your AsyncTask, there you have the response from the service (sent by the background process), handle it as you need.

If you need the data back in your class, you can send the AsyncTask a reference to it and call one class method from your AsyncTask sending it the required data

Just one way of doing it, there are more.

Dummy example:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private MyClass myClass;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return something;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String something) {
        super.onPostExecute(something);
        if(myClass != null){
             myClass.thereYouGo(something);
        }
    }
}
```

From your class (MyClass):

```
    new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
```

Receiver method in MyClass:

```
    public void thereYouGo(String something){
         // do what you want
    }
```